# how to convert java code to php?

Tags: php

I have this piece of code which is in java but i want it in php .
there is a function to convert hex to byte . and a main code:

```
public static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(String s)
{
int len = s.length();
byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
{
data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
+ Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
}
return data;
}
```

and here is main code :

```
public static String hmacSha1(String value, String key)
{
try
{
// Get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes byte[]
keyBytes = ConvertHexStringToByteArray(key);
SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
// Get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing
key Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(signingKey);
// Compute the hmac on input data bytes
byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
// Convert raw bytes to Hex
byte[] hexBytes = new Hex().encode(rawHmac);
// Covert array of Hex bytes to a String
return new String(hexBytes, "UTF-8");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $key = $CPCode . $service_id . $price . $timestamp . $request_id;
        $key = strtolower($key);
        $buffer1 = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($key); $i++){
            $buffer1[] = ord($key[$i]);
        }

        $buffer2 = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($auth_key); $i++){
            $buffer2[] = ord($auth_key[$i]);
        }

        $ret1 = hash_hmac('sha1', implode("", $buffer1), implode("", $buffer2), false);
        $ret1 = strtolower(str_replace('-', '', $ret1));
        return $ret1;
    }

Comment: php already has the `ConvertHexStringToByteArray` function built-in, it's called [hex2bin()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) - but that doesn't give you a php-array, it gives you a php-string, but php-strings are just an array of bytes. if you want a php-array from it, do `str_split(hex2bin($hex),1);`

Answer (score 0):

Hello

Your Java code in php is same as blow :

```
$key = strtolower($CPCode.$service_id.$price.$timestamp.$request_id);
$authKey = $CPCode;
$sign = hash_hmac("sha1",$key,$authKey);
```

Good Luck